# Uploading iOS dSYM files to Fabric Crashlytics with curl

Tags: ios, curl, crashlytics, twitter-fabric

Is it possible to upload iOS dSYM files to Fabric Crashlytics using curl?
It seems to me that this should be a simple `-XPOST` or `-XPUT`, but instead I am forced to use tools that are barely documented and not backwards compatible.

I would like something as simple as

`curl -F fabric_key=<key> \
  -F build_secret=<secret> \
  -F dsym_zipfile=@<path-to-zip> \
  https://fabric.io/api/v2/upload-dsyms`

Does something like this exist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mike from Fabric here.

Currently, you can't use curl to upload the dSYMs. What you can use is the [upload-symbols](https://docs.fabric.io/apple/crashlytics/missing-dsyms.html#upload-symbols-script) script which is similar. Locally from terminal, I run:

```
~/Applications/Fabric.app/Contents/MacOS/upload-symbols \
 -a YourAPIKey -p ios PathToDsymsToUpload
```

Comment: Thanks Mike, this can work, but can `PathToDsymsToUpload`, be a zipfile?

Comment: To answer my own question: Yes, zipfiles are supported.

Comment: @andersjanmyr. However, it looks like Fabric uncompresses the archive and uploads dSyms one by one

Comment: Yes, that's correct. We decompress them and do a conversion to make sure we can correctly upload the symbols. A dSYM contains much more then the symbols we need for symbolication, so we strip that data out and only submit the needed files.